# Set cookies in javascript - intergrated with pop up

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

my website now run javascript pop up in homepage , now i want to do when user click homepage , user will go to homepage and javascript pop will show , but after click close, and when user click again to homepage this javascript will not run, this script only active for one day.

So, how to intergrated cookies with my javascript pop up ?

**this pop up run perfectly but only left cookies script*

url http://tsubamecorp.com/home/index.php?route=extras/blog/getblogcategory&blogpath=41

this is my javascript pop up :

```
<script>

    var $xx = jQuery.noConflict();

    $xx(document).ready(function() {

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $xx('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $xx(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $xx(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $xx(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $xx('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $xx('#mask').fadeIn(1000);  
        $xx('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.90);   

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $xx(window).height();
        var winW = $xx(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $xx(id).css('top',  winH/2-$xx(id).height()/1);
        $xx(id).css('left', winW/2-$xx(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $xx(id).fadeIn(1000); 

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $xx('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $xx('#mask').hide();
        $xx('.window').hide();
    });             

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { $xx('a[href="#dialog1"]:eq(0)').click();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Not very sure about your question: "this script only active for one day.", did you mean that within one day, each user can see the popup window once, while another day comes, will see it once again?

Comment: Where is the cookie that you were talking about. Please explain your problem more clearly, the title is a bit misleading. Do you want to disable popup after one click?

Comment: ok you go here http://tsubamecorp.com/home/index.php?route=extras/blog/getblogcategory&blogpath=41 ..the problem is when user click home button this pop up will show everytime when user click..i want allow this pop up run one time only in one day..

Comment: i know the solutions is set cookies..but i don't know how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

something like this. a cookie's expires mean after the time the cookie will be deleted by sys. google some document.cookie

```
 Cookie = {
    get:function  ( key ) {
        var ret = this.toObj()[key];
        if( ret === undefined ){
            return ret;
        }
        return unescape ( this.toObj()[key] );
    },
    set:function  ( key, value, expires ) {
        if ( expires ){
            var exdata = new Date();
            exdata = exdata.setDate ( exdata.setDate() + expires ).toGMTString();
        }
        document.cookie = key+"="+escape(value) + ( exdata ? "; expires= " + exdata : "");
    },
    remove:function  ( key ) {
        document.cookie = key+"=remove;expires="+(new Date).toGMTString();
    },
    toJSON:function  (  ) {
        return JSON.stringify( this.toObj );
    },
    toObj:function  (  ) {
        var ret={}, cookiearr = document.cookie.split(";");
        var i, start, key, value;
        for ( i = 0; l = cookiearr[ i++ ];) {
            start = l.indexOf ("=");
            ret [ l.slice(0, start) ] = l.slice (start+1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```